# Find a string in a text few times and do action each time

Tags: c#, watin

I want to find all strings in a text with WatiN. 
I can find the first string, but i can't gather all of them.
For example I want find all occurrences of "water" in this text:

> There is a lot of water on earth. But not all water is drinkable.

So here I should find 2 "water". My code only finds the first one. How can I find both of them?

My code is:

```
IE ie = new IE("http://examplesite.com");

Element test = ie.Table(Find.ByClass("dataTable")).Element("td");

ie.TableRow(Find.ByText(t => t.Contains("example string"))).TextField(Find.ByName("examplename")).Button(Find.ByValue("example value")).Click();

ie.WaitForComplete();
Console.WriteLine("finished");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use IndexOf in a loop to find multiple occurrences of a substring.

```
const string haystack = "there are lots of water in the earth. but all of water arent drinkble.";
const string needle = "water";

var startIndex = -1;
while ((startIndex = haystack.IndexOf(needle, startIndex + 1)) > -1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found {0} at {1}", needle, startIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string then grab all the entries that contain what you're looking for.

```
var sentence = "There is a lot of water on earth. But not all water is drinkable."
var parts = sentence.Split(' ');
var words = parts.Where(p => p == "water");
```

Comment: Or just do `parts.Count(p => p == "water")`. Having a list where all items are "water" doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: The original question is pretty vague on why he wants to do this. I have no idea what is useful to him or not.

Comment: yes i think it was not usefull ( didnt try ur code yet ),  i want to find few element with same id name.  and change all of thire values. for example i want to find all textbox with id "test, and change thire value  to something else.